# Compare strings by matching words

Tags: sql, database, string, algorithm, postgresql

I'd like to know if such an algorithm exists and is implemented in any database (ideally Postgres).

Levenstein matches strings, but I'd like to compare strings based on the number of matching words. For example, having:

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

I should come with a result of *2* if i try to match it against

```
the pen lies over the table
```

because it matched "the" and  "over" on both the sentences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a SQL method using arrays:

```
select count(*) from
(
(select distinct unnest(string_to_array(upper('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'),' ')))
intersect all
(select distinct unnest(string_to_array(upper('the pen lies over the table'),' ')))
) t3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/724f7/6

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the same algorithms designed for letters also for words. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055839/word-level-edit-distance-of-a-sentence). Comparing by words is not common and I'm pretty sure that PostgreSQL doesn't support it (nor any other database I know). However as long as you can use arrays, as suggested in answer by David Aldridge, you can write your own stored procedure for this.

You can take inspiration for the algorithm on [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance#Java), just replacing `String`s for `List<String>`, `size()` for `length()` and `char` comparison for `equals()` would work. Now you can implement the same in SQL, all you need is array allocation (and some index arithmetic if you cannot use two-dimensional arrays). In the worst case, you can use a temporary table instead of arrays.