# Levenshtein distance in R on sentence level

Tags: r, distance, levenshtein-distance

How can i do Levenshtein distance measurement on word (not character) Level in R?

See the following:

Expected result 1)

```
# levenshtein operations needed: Delete*2 --> 2 operations
array1 <- c("word", "car")
array2 <- c("word", "pool", "beer", "car")
```

I am seeking a function `levenshtein()`, so that the distance of 2 is returned for the example above:

```
levenshtein(array1, array2)
--> 2
```

Expected result 2)

```
# levenshtein operations needed: Delete and insert --> 2 operations
array1 <- c("word", "car", "pool")
array2 <- c("word", "pool", "car")
```

I am seeking a function `levenshtein()`, so that the distance of 2 is returned for the example above:

```
levenshtein(array1, array2)
--> 2
```

I found the following:
[Word-level edit distance of a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055839/word-level-edit-distance-of-a-sentence)
But i didnt find a working needleman-wunsch implentation that yields the expected results, described above.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking... but is this what you are after?

```
lapply(array1, function(i){
    m <- drop(attr(adist(i, array2, counts = TRUE), "counts")) 
    row.names(m) <- array2
    setNames(list(m %>% as.data.frame()), i)
}) %>% unlist(recursive = FALSE)
$word
     ins del sub
word   0   0   0
pool   0   0   3
beer   1   1   2
car    0   1   2

$car
     ins del sub
word   1   0   2
pool   1   0   3
beer   1   0   2
car    0   0   0
```

Comment: hi Carl, thanks for your Response. I am not sure your answer would return the distance of 2 for both examples? I made an edit to the example in case it was unclear.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are asking I think. Are you looking to find all occurances in array2 that have a combined edit distance of 2, such that `insertions + deletions = 2`? What's the actual goal here; in lay-terms @ThanksGuys ?

Answer (score 0):

We can map the unique words to `letters`, and use `adist` as the engine for the generalized edit distance.

```
levenshtein <- function(x, y){
  unique_words <- unique(c(x,y))
  letter_x <- plyr::mapvalues(x,
                              from = unique_words,
                              to = letters[1:length(unique_words)])
  letter_y <- plyr::mapvalues(y,
                              from = unique_words,
                              to = letters[1:length(unique_words)])
  adist(paste0(letter_x,collapse=''),paste0(letter_y,collapse=''))
}

array1 <- c("word", "car")
array2 <- c("word", "pool", "beer", "car")

levenshtein(array1, array2)


array1 <- c("word", "car", "pool")
array2 <- c("word", "pool", "car")

levenshtein(array1, array2)
```

Apparently, this function can only work for two character vectors with less than or equal to 26 unique words, you can generalize it to 52 (adding upper case `Letters`), or 62 (digits), etc. ...

The better approach apparently would be rewriting the `adist` function...